# Не отправляется POST запрос через AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Работаю на фреймворке Codeigniter, не могу отправить простой POST ajax запрос. Вот мой код

```
  $('#newTableForm').submit(function (){
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "/createTable",
      data: [],
      dataType: "JSON",
      contentType: false,
      processData: false
    }).done(function (message) {
      console.log(message);
    })
  })
```

Сам Url на который я отправляю запрос рабочий
Загвоздка в том что как только я меняю method на GET то запрос проходит без проблем.
Кто может сказать причину такого поведения?

Comment: Покажите роут и в нетворк смотрите ошибку

Comment: @InDevX
https://prnt.sc/12xbgek Вот что выходит в нетворке. 
А это роуты

`$routes->get('/newTable', 'TableController::newTableView');`
`$routes->get('/createTable', 'TableController::createTable');`

Comment: Включаем логику. `$routes->get` - `меняю method на GET то запрос проходит без проблем`. А что будет, если роут сменить на  `$routes->post`?